How to change the styling of FloatButton from AntDesign?
I am trying to customize my FloatButton component some custom CSS and can't find out how to do it for the background color and for the Icon that is displayed in it. I tested with this code but it seems to work only for the background when hovering but not when not hovering. Also the color for the Icon seems to not change:

When not hovering:



When hovering:



The code is:

style={{
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        color: "white",
      }}
      onMouseEnter={(e) => {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        e.currentTarget.style.color = "black";
      }}
      onMouseLeave={(e) => {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        e.currentTarget.style.color = "white";
      }}


Any ideas?

NOTE:
I added a few properties to try figuring out what's happening and I saw weird stuff:

icon={<FileTextOutlined />}
badge={{ count: 12 }}
description="Very very very big text"

And it looks like this:



The layout issue is fixed if I use "square" as the shape but I want to use "circle". However the problem remains even with square.

The default type of the FloatButton is default and it automatically adds white background color and black color.
In order to set custom colors, you can simply add type="text" to your FloatButton like this:
<FloatButton
    type="text"
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      color: 'white',
    }}
    onMouseEnter={(e) => {
      e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      e.currentTarget.style.color = 'black';
    }}
    onMouseLeave={(e) => {
      e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      e.currentTarget.style.color = 'white';
    }}
/>

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example of your sample code.
